# Concatenate mysql column values in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, angularjs

I have a table like:

```
client_id   |   name   |   bank_name
------------------------------------
    1       |   Steve  |    Bank 1 
    1       |   Steve  |    Bank 1
    1       |   Steve  |    Bank 3
```

I want to print out a statement as following:

```
Client: Steve

Current bank: Bank 1, Bank 3
```

Here is my current code. (Keep in mind I am printing this in a template pdf so ignore the php and div tags, they are correct as is.):

```
<?php
    $currentBank = '';
    foreach($data as $bank){
        $currentBank .= $bank->bank_name;

?>
            <div>Current bank: {{ $currentBank }} </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Can anyone help me achieve the wanted formatting, ignoring the duplicate items and printing out in the format : 'Bank 1, Bank2'.

Currently with my code, my output is:

```
Current bank: Bank1
Current bank: Bank1Bank1
Current bank: Bank1Bank1Bank3
```

Note: I cannot use `DISTINCT` in my sql query as another section of the template requires me to print out everything including duplicates

Comment: How about using `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: Note that you should NOT be doing thiws kind of processing server-side. What if you want to display the same data in a different way? Are you going to execute another query, or just manipulate the DOM?

Comment: @Strawberry so you're saying that everyone's name in the database will always be Steve

Comment: I'm saying that while the name is steve, do one thing. When it changes, do something else. This is a basic operation within a loop.

Comment: @Strawberry this does not solve the problem.

Comment: What part of the problem does it fail to address? And what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Is client_id=1 Steve the same as client_id=3 Steve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spend a entire for loop looping through all available data.  Collect the names into a new array because this allows us an easy way to get uniques with array_unique.  Another option would be to store the bankNames as the key in the array - see second example

```
<?
    $currentBank = '';
    $bankNameList = [];
    foreach($data as $bank):
        $bankNameList[] = $bank->bank_name;
    }
    $bankNameList = array_unique($bankNameList);
    $currentBank = implode(', ', $bankNameList);

?>
            <div>Current bank: {{ $currentBank }} </div>
<? endfor; ?>
```

second example without array_unique()

```
<?
    $currentBank = '';
    $bankNameList = [];
    foreach($data as $bank):
        $bankNameList[$bank->bank_name]++;
    }
    $currentBank = implode(', ', array_keys($bankNameList));

?>
            <div>Current bank: {{ $currentBank }} </div>
<? endfor; ?>
```

The even bestest way would be to organize this data outside of the template with named helper functions.  That way, your template doesn't grow to thousands of undocumented lines

```
<?

/**
 * Return all $item->bank_names
 * as comma delimited string
 */
public function concatAllBankNames($data) {

        $bankNameList = [];
        foreach($data as $bank):
            $bankNameList[$bank->bank_name]++;
        }
        return implode(', ', array_keys($bankNameList));
}

//.. in some controller
foreach ($databasedata as $row) {
  $row[ $row['username'] ]['bank_names_concat'] = $this->concatAllBankNames($row['data']);

}
//assign data to template system somehow
$template->rows = $rows;
//or
$template['rows'] = $rows;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question in SQL is:

```
select name, group_concat(distinct bank_name)
from t
group by name;
```

I don't understand how that fits into the rest of your application.  I can say that you should be doing this processing in the database rather than using loops on the application side.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in SQL:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bank_name) FROM table GROUP BY client_id;
```

Comment: This needs to be done in php as the set of data is used elsewhere in the document. This also does not ignore duplicates.

Comment: @st3lz added `DISTINCT` to manage the duplicates. About the dataset: just query a dataset, just for this list.